# WMI call works in GUI thread (STA Thread), why does it fail in background threads (MTA Threads)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wmi, apartments

Okay, I have a method which simply backs up the Windows event logs as *.evt files.
In .net2.0 on Windows XP x86 and x64, this worked great, no issues.

We recently upgraded to .net4.0 (4.0.3 specifically) and now this code is failing in a very specific way. (Fails on XP x86 and x64, Win7 works fine)

If the method is executed by the main GUI thread in an event handler, it works fine.
If however this method is executed in a new Thread, or by the ThreadPool, it fails with an Access Denied error.

This application is being run as an administrator and accessing the local computer wmi provider.

I would guess that there is some kind of thread security new in .net4 that I have not satisfied or something like that.

Here is some sample code which illustrates the problem.
This was from a form with 3 buttons, the handlers are at the end and illustrates when it works and when it fails. 
It saves a copy of all Windows event logs to ..\Log folder.

Compiling the below with target framework of .Net2.0, all three calling methods work fine.
Compiling with target framework of .Net4.0.3, and the last 2 calling methods fail with Access Denied.

What am I missing here?

```
    public void ExportWindowsEventLogs(object ignored)
    {
        try
        {
               ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_NTEventlogFile");

               searcher.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;    // Defaults to False which gives AccessDenied errors so
               foreach (ManagementObject oEventLogFile in searcher.Get())
               {
                   string LogName = oEventLogFile["LogfileName"] as string;
                   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LogName))
                   {
                       // Obtain in-parameters for the method
                       ManagementBaseObject inParams =
                           oEventLogFile.GetMethodParameters("BackupEventlog");
                       // Add the input parameters.
                       string strPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\..\Log\" + LogName + "-Exported.Evt";
                       inParams["ArchiveFileName"] = strPath;

                       //Delete the old backup if it exists, as the WMI BackupEventLog method does not overwrite old files.
                       FileInfo backupFile = new FileInfo(strPath);
                       if (!backupFile.Directory.Exists)
                           backupFile.Directory.Create();
                       else if (backupFile.Exists)
                           backupFile.Delete();

                       InvokeMethodOptions options = new InvokeMethodOptions();

                       // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
                       //FAILS ON NEXT LINE WITH ACCESS DENIED ERROR,
                       //but oEventLogFile.ToString() works fine.
                       ManagementBaseObject outParams =
                           oEventLogFile.InvokeMethod("BackupEventlog", inParams, null);
                       object returnValue =  oEventLogFile.InvokeMethod("BackupEventlog", new object[] { strPath });
                   }
               }
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while trying to execute the WMI method: " + err.ToString());
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //WORKS
        ExportWindowsEventLogs(null);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Access Denied error
        Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExportWindowsEventLogs));
        workerThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
        workerThread.Start(true);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Access Denied error
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ExportWindowsEventLogs, null);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
This appears to be directly related to the Thread.ApartmentState setting of the executing thread.
By default threads are created with ApartmentState.MTA, whereas the main GUI thread is an STA thread. 
In .Net 4.0, My WMI code works when running in an STA thread, but does not work on the MTA threads. In .Net 2.0, it works in both.

Any ideas how to get it to work in an MTA thread on .Net 4.0? I'd like to use the threadpool to run this.

Comment: At what point did you start setting EnablePrivileges to true?  Are you impersonating the user account at all?

Comment: Oh, been that way for at least a year.  Not impersonating the user account either.  You are seeing the complete code.  This runs as an administrator as part of some machine control software.  The big question is why does it work on the GUI thread but not a different thread in .net 4. Worked fine in 2.0.

Comment: why the requirement to use an MTA Thread or the Threadpool?